# Airflow cannot establish SFTP connection using encrypted private key

Tags: airflow, sftp, paramiko, google-cloud-composer, pysftp

I am trying to establish a SFTP connection in Airflow 1.10.14 with the `SFTPOperator` from `airflow.providers.sftp.operators.sftp` or `airflow.contrib.operators.sftp_operator`.

The contrib operator and the providers package are equivalent ("providers" packages are backported from Airflow 2.0 which do not make use of the contrib operators anymore), and depend on the same Python modules: `paramiko`, `pysftp`, and `sshtunnel`.

My `pip freeze`:

```
paramiko==2.7.2 (latest release)
pysftp==0.2.9 (latest release)
sshtunnel==0.1.5 (latest release is 0.4.0)
```

It works fine with a simple user/password and a private key without a passphrase but it fails when I use an encrypted key protected by a passphrase:

- "ERROR - private key file is encrypted" when I set "private_key_passphrase" param alone in the connection
- "ERROR - Authentication failed" when I set the "password" alone or both "password" and "private_key_passphrase".

Note that it works well in all cases with the `SSHOperator` (in this case, the key passphrase is set in the "password" param), thus I believe the problem is in the `pysftp` module.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please review the extra param name, the correct name is `private_key_pass`
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.14/airflow/contrib/hooks/sftp_hook.py#L60-L61

Comment: Thanks! This was a little bit confusing between `SSHHook`, which already manages a `private_key_passphrase`, and `SFTPHook` with its `private_key_pass`. I submitted a PR so that the arguments naming is more consistent: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/14028